# Show progress bar with percentage while downloading file using handler

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, browser, progress-bar

I want to download `.EXE` file on button click and show download progress bar on web page instead of browser progress bar. The idea behind this development is that browser hides it's download progress bar inside his download manager.

> I want to run this `.EXE` automatically after download reached out to
>   100%.

I have tried to develop some code like below. It just download file when you see in your browser console but couldn't show progress bar and percentage.

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Download" onclick="downfile();" />
</div>
<div id="progressCounter"></div>
```

**JavaScript Logic:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function downfile() {
        var myTrigger;
        var progressElem = $('#progressCounter');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Download.ashx',
            beforeSend: function (thisXHR) {
                myTrigger = setInterval(function () {
                    if (thisXHR.readyState > 2) {
                        var totalBytes = thisXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-length');
                        var dlBytes = thisXHR.responseText.length;
                        (totalBytes > 0) ? progressElem.html(Math.round((dlBytes / totalBytes) * 100) + "%") : progressElem.html(Math.round(dlBytes / 1024) + "K");
                    }
                }, 200);
            },
            complete: function () {
                clearInterval(myTrigger);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert('done');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Download.ashx**

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string filename = "ccsetup403.exe";
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" +filename);
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + filename);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bin);
        context.Response.End();
        fs.Close();
  }
```

**Most welcome to other ideas.**

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You think there is an option in the browser to download an executable file, hide the progressbar and then run the file on its own?

Comment: No...I want to except browser download and have to display same process on my web page. For example like: https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/. I want to do this same process on my web page.